# How to build a koolplot library using VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, bgi

I want to use simple plotting functions in my C++ code. Presently I am using Qt5 with VS2010 c++ compiler. I came across this library called [koolplot](http://koolplot.codecutter.org/). But I cannot buid it with VS2010 from its source files. I am opening vs2010 cmd and running nmake...It shows winbgim.h missing..I copied that header in MinGW include folder and ran it ...now it shows `"Plotdata.h:warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration"` Please help...if any one knows a simple plotting library running with VS2010 please suggest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its website, Koolplot is designed for the MinGW/gcc toolchain - you'll have to do a bit of leg work to get it to compile on Visual Studio, though I don't know specifically what you'd have to do without taking a closer look.

Also, the library seems to do its own window management and the like, so I'm not sure how well you'll be able to integrate it with Qt.

Answer (score 1):

koolplot needs WinBGI library (BGI = Borland Graphics Interface?).
I have changed it to use native Win32 using VS2008:

http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/hs/koolplot-heha.zip/

It's still incomplete as a good Win32 implementation would implement koolplot in a DLL which self-registers a Window class, and has both C and C++ interface. Moreover, koolplot as-is doesn't support multiple scales, finer plotting options, GDIplus, and fast data update, so it's not the right thing to write an oscilloscope program.
It's C++ code is also outdated as there are lambda functions available now.

However, good integrating into Qt is another task.

Comment: Hi, I see there are several packages under your page: https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/hs/free.var, such as `koolplot-heha.zip` and `koolplot-template-2017.zip`, I'm not sure which are the latest version? Thanks.

Comment: FYI: I have created a github repo to put your code, and make a simple Code::Blocks project, and the project can be built under MSYS2/MinGW GCC compiler, see here: [asmwarrior/koolplot](https://github.com/asmwarrior/koolplot)